# How is Bumblebee able to use his own voice?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-the-last-knight

In the live-action universe, Bumblebee had his voice unit destroyed by Megatron long ago. In *Transformers: The Last Knight* Cade is still trying to fix Bumblebee, but

> the voice unit they find doesn't match correctly, and he ends up with a different voice,

so he continues using the radio to "speak".

... Until

> he suddenly, but briefly uses his own voice to talk to Nemesis/Optimus Prime to get him to remember who he is

and then goes right back to using the radio.

### How is Bumblebee able to use his real voice momentarily?

Comment: Was it his _real_ voice, or just the one he gets from the other voice unit? If it's actually his real voice, that sounds like a continuity error.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo He speaks to Prime, and Prime replies something to the effect of, "Bumblebee, I haven't heard your real voice since Cybertron fell"

Comment: First off....that could also still realte to the "different" voice as its still his own voice and not just radio cuts.  Secondly it wouldnt bet the first continuity error anyway....shall we talk about bumble getting his old voice back thanks to some all spark in transformers 1? :)

Comment: Should be noted that Bumblebee did use his real voice in Transformers 1 after the ending fight with Megatron.

Answer (score 2):

This one is a little tough to explain without saying something like *"because of the power of friendship."* Part of the difficulty is due to the fact that Bumblebee's voice problems are a construct of the movies, so we can't really look to other material to explain it.

My best explanation for this is that as Nemesis Prime is about to finish Bumblebee off, he grabs Bumblebee's throat. **It is possible that maybe the act of choking Bee readjusted some circuits in his voice box and temporarily allowed him to speak normally.**

Comment: The voicebox he has in him at the time isn't his own. I'm not sure how squeezing it would temporarily fix it, or accidentally make it exactly/so close to his original voice that Prime would recognize it as the original.

Comment: @phantom42 He actually ripped the new voicebox out as soon as he realized it was a Siri voice, not matching his own. I think the details as to how his voice is broken are fuzzy enough that he doesn't have to *literally* have his original voicebox back in order to speak with his own voice. There is just something wrong with his voice that no one seems to know how to fix, so yeah... it's like smacking your tv to get the picture to clear up for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what Bumblebee said was just a recording of what he has said before, that way he probably wouldn't need his voice to say it.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this or is it just speculation?

Answer (score 0):

**Will Power**

You are treating Transformers like they are ordinary machines/robots we use in real world. They are digital organisms more complex than even humans. If I go out of canon, they have been created from digital gods who are even older than the universe. Their bodies can adapt, repair itself just like human bodies and their bodies are certainly more capable as they can transform into anything.

Let's look at them according to the canon:

- They have consciousness. Megatron was able to transfer his consciousness into a new body.
- They can feel pain. I heard in the recent movie: "Ah, that hurts."
- They can transform into anything at microscopic level. Although it looks like their macroscopic body parts are readjusting just like their toys, at times they change at microscopic level. For example, they are able to copy external design of luxury cars. Also, their engines become faster meaning the changes happen at deep levels.
- They can become psychopath... sorry, sociopath.
- The robot of the last point was able to become emotional. Think last scene when the old man died. Other Transformers also show emotions all the time.
- The same robot became Beethoven out of mood and whatnot (now, I want him as my personal assistant... Sorry JARVIS).
- Optimus Prime lost hope in the last movie and he got back on the feet only after some encouragements.

Transformers definitely are similar to humans to exercise will. So, my guess: Bumblebee's strong will at the moment fixed his voice box temporarily (which technically shouldn't be impossible because their bodies have ability to transform at microscopic levels.

**Power of Will (of course, human will) in case you don't know (only scientific):**

- You are sick and you don't have enough energy to even walk. Suddenly, a snake comes in front of you and you'd jump. This one is easiest to explain: Adrenaline Rush.
- There are medical cases of real returning of voice when he/she has strong urge to speak.
- [Will to Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_to_live)
- [Placebo Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placebo): Medicines don't have 100% contribution in healing. People's beliefs in the treatment also contribute. Research shows that lots of people get healed even with fake/placebo pills when they believe that doctor is actually giving him proper medicines. Yes, even prayers work if you have true belief in it. It's not God who heals you. It's your own head.

See, we don't have nano-scale transformation capability and yet we are able to heal ourselves with will power. Think why Bumblebee's voice can't return back to normal for a moment.